# I need to use zLib1.dll with Visual Basic .NET

Tags: .net, zlib

I am working my way through some ancient C code that uses zLib1.dll to decompress a propitiatory file. I need an example of how I can get to the "uncompress" function in the DLL using Visual Basic .NET.

I know this might come up so here are a few of the things I have looked into:

1. I do know there is a .NET wrapper for zLib1.dll. In fact its even in the zip file if you download the source. The problem with that is the help file (chm) will not open for me so I can't get at the documentation to read it

   2. This may be a work around... I have seen people mention using the built in compression... but does that work EXACTLY like zLib? I will do no good to try and uncompress a file if it's not using the same algorithms as zLib.
   3. Please don't just suggest I use winzip or something else like that because it won't work. These propitiatory files have special headers that canned packages will not understand. I have to be able to uncompress specific bytes in the files.

Comment: I have two suggestions for you: Try decompressing the file with the built-in functionality and see if it works. If that fails, google how to open chm files on the system you are using.

Comment: - and a third, if my first suggestion didn't work: write an app in `ancient C` that can decompress the proprietary file, then (re)compress it with an algorithm that .NET has built-in support for.

Comment: In case anyone comes across this I figured out the answer to my own question (sort of).

    `<DllImport("ZLib1.dll", EntryPoint:="uncompress")> _    
Public Shared Function uncompress(ByRef dest As Byte(), ByVal destlen As ULong, ByRef src As Byte(), ByVal srclen As ULong) As Integer
    End Function `

The only problem is, while it access the function and does just what I told it to do... it doen't work. Throws an access violation so back to the drawing board....

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question (sort of) it does look like the built in compression works just fine. This was my final solution: (AltDecompress is where the decompression is done and it calls GetDataBlock which I have included for clarity

```
Public Function AltDecompress(data As Byte()) As Byte()
    Dim output = New MemoryStream()

    Dim tmp As Byte() = GetDataBlock(data, 2)  ' using .NET we have to strip the zLib header
    Using compressedStream = New MemoryStream(tmp)
        Using zlibStream = New DeflateStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Decompress)
            zlibStream.CopyTo(output)
            zlibStream.Close()
            output.Position = 0
            Return output.ToArray
        End Using
    End Using
End Function


Public Function GetDataBlock(ByRef Data As Byte(), ByVal start As Integer, Optional ByVal len As Integer = 0) As Byte()
    ' Extract a datablock from another datablock
    ' if len is not specified it will copy the entire block from the starting point to the end
    Dim BlockLen As Integer = Data.Length - start           ' Calculate the length of the data block

    ' Check if len was specified
    If len = 0 Then
        ' if not grab everything from start to end
        BlockLen = Data.Length - start
    Else
        ' Grab just the data asked for
        BlockLen = len
    End If

    Dim tmpBlock(BlockLen) As Byte   ' Create the target array
    Array.ConstrainedCopy(Data, start, tmpBlock, 0, BlockLen)   ' Copy the data
    Return tmpBlock  ' return the block

End Function
```